# Split selected features with selected line from another layer not creating all new features

Tags: qgis, digitizing, tools

Trying to use the split selected features with selected line from another layer to split a polyline in 2.

[image: PolyLineSplit]

I run the tool and get the following output:

[image: SPlitPolys]

In the attribute table there are now 2 features, but the one split on the right is the only one that can be seen in the map. If I select the other original poly it is not there, but as you can see the nodes are.

It seems like the tool squashed my original poly, thought it is still represented in the attribute table and gave me a new poly seen in the second image. What am I missing here?

I was hoping to get 2 new polys in addition to the original one in the first photo. I've checked projections and topology and should be good there.

Comment: Which tool did you use?

Comment: split selected features with selected line from another layer, from the 'Digitizing Tools' plugin

Comment: If you have invalid geometry that could make this tool behave strangely. Check for invalid geometry by running the Topology Checker plugin with the rule "[your layer] must not have invalid geometries."